# Geocoder looking for latitude and longitude fields but they don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm using the [Rails Geocoder Gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), Rails 4.2 and MySqL. I want to detect how many travels are compatible with some boxes.

Travels and boxes have these fields: `departure_address`, `departure_lat`, `departure_long` and `arrival_address`, `arrival_lat`, `arrival_long`.

When I want to check if a travel is compatible with a box I try with this query:

```
Travel.near([Box.last.departure_lat, Box.last.departure_long], 50)
```

I know it is considering only `departure_address` and not `arrival_address` but anyway it doesn't work because Geocoder tries to find a 'latitude' field in table 'travels' even if I called it 'dep_lat' and so on for longitude.

I want to solve this problem and then think to combine it with arrivals. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to specify to GeoCoder that you aren't wanting to use their default `lat` and `lon` attribute names.

To do this, add the following line to your model:

```
geocoded_by :departure_address, :latitude  => :departure_lat, :longitude => :departure_lon # ActiveRecord
```

You would do the same for your arrivals, but change the names of course.

From the docs:

> You are not stuck with using the latitude and longitude database column names (with ActiveRecord). For example:
>
> geocoded_by :address, :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lon # ActiveRecord

More information about this can be found in the [Model Configuration](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#model-configuration) section of the GeoCoder docs.

Comment: I didn't think about it because I'm using a special method in my model but it's so obvious!! Thank you very much however!!!!